# Does Geotools support isobaric and isotherm lines drawing?

Tags: java, geotools, weather

Is there any way to draw isobaric and isotherm lines with Geotools? Are there any examples how to do this in the official documentation or not?

Comment: Have you seen this https://blog.ianturton.com/geotools/2020/12/24/contours.html?

Comment: Not yet. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Do you have points or a raster? Either way the short answer is yes

Comment: I have no  gridded dataset of a terrain. The question is about how to build isobars and isotherms basing on the forecast or factual atmospheric pressure and temperature data? Is there any module in geotools which provides a support of visualizing such meteorological processes or not? Maybe you can provide some general example how to do this or redirect me to additional guides or instructions related to this issue?

Comment: Did you read also the part "How to contour a set of points?" It does not make any difference if the data values express heights, temperatures, or pressure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @user30184 points out I wrote some contouring code in 2020 and merged the result into the main GeoTools library

So given an input `FeatureCollection` of points (`input`) you can create contours (or isobars, isotherms etc) and save as a shapefile (or other format) using:

```
  org.geotools.process.vector.ContourProcess vcp = new org.geotools.process.vector.ContourProcess();
  SimpleFeatureCollection results = vcp.execute(input, "propertyVa", levels, 0.0, true, true, null);
  File vec_contours = new File("vector-contours.shp");
  DataStore ods = fac.createNewDataStore(Collections.singletonMap(fac.URLP.key, URLs.fileToUrl(vec_contours)));
  SimpleFeatureType schema = results.getSchema();

  ods.createSchema(schema);
  SimpleFeatureStore store = (SimpleFeatureStore) ods.getFeatureSource(ods.getTypeNames()[0]);
  store.addFeatures(results);
```

Comment: I've got it. I couldn't understant the role of existing shape file and its destiny. Thank you for your clarifying answer.